# TlistView item Textbutton/Glyphbutton Onclick event

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

How does one call the Onclick event of a FMX Listview **Textbutton** or **Glyphbutton**?

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnClick holds a pointer to a method.

You can call the method directly, but it's good practise to make sure the event handler is assigned.

```
if assigned(MyTextButton.Onclick) then MyTextButton.OnClick(Self);
```